# Analytical solution to an almost Gaussian integral

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, expected-value

I have the probability distribution below. It cropped up from converting a normal probability distribution for radii of spheres to a distribution for the volume of the spheres.

$$f_V(v) = \left(\frac{1}{36 \pi}\right)^{1/3}v^{-2/3}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\left(\left(\frac{3}{4\pi}\right)^{1/3}v^{1/3} - \mu \right)^2}{\sigma^2}\right)$$

I want to find a close formed solution for the expectation value of $v$:

$$E(v) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}vf_V(v)dv$$

But am failing. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is much easier to take the expected value $\mathbb E[\frac43 \pi R^3]$ when $R \sim \textrm{Normal}(\mu, \sigma)$ directly.

We have $R = \sigma Z + \mu$ where $Z \sim \textrm{Normal}(0,1)$, and we know that $\mathbb E[Z^2] = 1$ while (by symmetry around the origin) $\mathbb E[Z^3] = \mathbb E[Z] = 0$.  Therefore $\mathbb E[R^3] = \mathbb E[\sigma^3 Z^3 + 3 \sigma^2 \mu Z^2 + 3 \sigma \mu^2 Z + \mu^3]$ which simplifies to just $3\sigma^2\mu + \mu^3$. From there,  $\mathbb E[\frac43 \pi R^3] = \frac43\pi(3\sigma^2\mu + \mu^3)$.

Of course, a normal distribution can at best be an approximation to a distribution of the radius of a sphere, since the radius can never be negative!

Comment: Thanks so much! This is great. Yes I' suppose i mean integration from 0 to infinity.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful with branch cuts when $v<0$.  But use this integral:

$$\int\limits_{v = 0}^{\infty} v^{1/3} e^{- v^{2/3}}\ dv = \frac{3}{2} .$$

Comment: Thanks!! It works out with this identity.

Comment: A recommendation to a relative newbie:  Simplify your question to its essence.  Did you really need $\left( \frac{1}{36 \pi} \right)^{1/3}$?  Of course not.  Did you really need the $\mu$ dependence?  Of course not.  The $\left( \frac{3}{4 \pi}\right)^{1/3}$?  Again, no.  Simplifying the problem to its essence will help *you* solve it... and garner more help from others.

Comment: No i did not need the coefficients, but I left them to keep the context of radii and volumes. This led to @Misha's answer which circumvents the integral completely.